# deploy an application in the jelastic marketplace

Tags: docker, registry, jelastic

So basically, this what we want to do: create an application and publish it in our jelastic provider.

To do that, we had this idea:

1. Create our customized docker images locally
2. create a registry in our jelastic provider
3. push our images into this registry
4. create a manifest in yaml that describes how the environment should be created

Basically, the manifest describes:

- what images should be used (our image and a jelastic storage)
- shell scripts to run on the dockers
- pops up a message when the installation succeed
- send mail also

My question is: Is that secure?? I mean if a user go to the marketplace and chooses to deploy our application, can he gets some registry information?

So you have any experience in this?

Thank you in advance
Regards

Comment: Yes, an advanced user can get credentials via /console logs. But, I believe you can create read-only acces to a specific image with specific credentials.

Comment: Also, cluster admin access is requested for adding your package to the marketplace, so only Jelastic provider (cluster owner) can do that.